# How to assign a custom SQL query which returns a collection of Rows as an attribute of an ORM model

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

For example, suppose I have three models: `Book`, `Author`, and `BookAuthor` where a book can have many authors and an author can have many books.

```
class BookAuthor(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'book_authors'
    author_id = Column(ForeignKey('authors.id'), primary_key=True)
    book_id = Column(ForeignKey('books.id'), primary_key=True)
    blurb = Column(String(50))

class Author(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'authors'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class Book(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'books'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

I would like to create an `authors` attribute of `Book` which returns every author for the book *and* the corresponding blurb about each author. Something like this

```
class Book(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'books'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    @authors.expression
    def authors(cls):
        strSQL = "my custom SQL query"
        return execute(strSQL)
```

---

### Demo

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, Session

# Make the engine
engine = create_engine("sqlite+pysqlite:///:memory:", future=True, echo=False)

# Make the DeclarativeMeta
Base = declarative_base()

class BookAuthor(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'book_authors'
    author_id = Column(ForeignKey('authors.id'), primary_key=True)
    book_id = Column(ForeignKey('books.id'), primary_key=True)
    blurb = Column(String(50))

class Author(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'authors'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class Book(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'books'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

# Create the tables in the database
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

# Make data
with Session(bind=engine) as session:

    # add parents
    a1 = Author()
    session.add(a1)

    a2 = Author()
    session.add(a2)

    session.commit()

    # add children
    b1 = Book()
    session.add(b1)

    b2 = Book()
    session.add(b2)

    session.commit()

    # map books to authors
    ba1 = BookAuthor(author_id=a1.id, book_id=b1.id, blurb='foo')
    ba2 = BookAuthor(author_id=a1.id, book_id=b2.id, blurb='bar')
    ba3 = BookAuthor(author_id=a2.id, book_id=b2.id, blurb='baz')

    session.add(ba1)
    session.add(ba2)
    session.add(ba3)

    session.commit()

# Get the authors for book with id 2
with Session(bind=engine) as session:
    s = """
        SELECT foo.* FROM (
            SELECT 
                authors.*, 
                book_authors.blurb, 
                book_authors.book_id 
            FROM authors INNER JOIN book_authors ON authors.id = book_authors.author_id
        ) AS foo
        INNER JOIN books ON foo.book_id = books.id
        WHERE books.id = :bookid
        """
    result = session.execute(s, params={'bookid':2}).fetchall()
    print(result)
```

See that semi-nasty query at the end? It successfully returns the authors for book 2, including the corresponding blurb about each author. I would like to create a `.authors` attribute of my `Book` model that executes this query.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The trick was to key was to use a [plain descriptor](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html#using-a-plain-descriptor) with [`object_session()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.object_session)

```
class Book(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'books'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    @property
    def authors(self):
        s = """
                SELECT foo.* FROM (
                    SELECT
                        authors.*,
                        book_authors.blurb,
                        book_authors.book_id
                    FROM authors INNER JOIN book_authors ON authors.id = book_authors.author_id
                ) AS foo
                INNER JOIN books ON foo.book_id = books.id
                WHERE books.id = :bookid
                """
        result = object_session(self).execute(s, params={'bookid': self.id}).fetchall()
        return result
```

Comment: Is there a way to use object session and load an ORM object without using the class method / property? Can you use a custom query like this and still load and object outside of a class?